# CSS border animation - convert solid lines to dotted lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a circle animation and it works fine, however I am trying to change from solid lines to dotted lines, but I am wondering how to get it done, can somebody please suggest?

Here is how it looks right now:

```css
#loading {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.outer-shadow, .inner-shadow {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.inner-shadow {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.hold {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 50px, 50px, 25px);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.fill, .dot span {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.fill {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 25px, 50px, 0px);
}
.left .fill {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: left 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: left 1s linear;
  animation: left 1s linear both;
}
@keyframes left {
0% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
transform:rotate(180deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes left {
0% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
}
.right {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.right .fill {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: right 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: right 1s linear;
  animation: right 1s linear both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes right {
0% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
transform:rotate(180deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes right {
0% {
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
}
.inner-shadow img {
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id='loading'>
  <div class='outer-shadow'> </div>
  <div class='inner-shadow'> </div>
  <div class='hold left'>
    <div class='fill'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='hold right'>
    <div class='fill'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    border-right-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-color: red;
  }
  75% {
    border-left-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    border-top-color: red;
    border-left-color: red;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-right-color: red;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Edit, Updated

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-left-style: dotted;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: .25s;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: border 1s ease-in .25s;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-right-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-color: red;
  }
  75% {
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-left-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    border: 2px dotted red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, is it possible to show from start to end? right now it looks infinite type

Comment: thanks for the updated answer, I have created something something similar, but your updated version is better than mine, so I will update my code with this now. thanks for your kind attention on this!

Answer (score 14):

Here is another snippet for your question. There is no genuine way to move dotted lines. Instead, I cover/uncover the dotted circle below with another circle with white border. Please see below:

```css
#c1 {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: red;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 5;
}

#c2 {
  animation: render 1s linear both;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: white;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 377;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

@keyframes render {
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 377;
    stroke-dashoffset: -377;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <circle id="c1" cx="120" cy="120" r="60" />
    <circle id="c2" cx="120" cy="120" r="60" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I would like to strongly recommend to use SVG as it will make your life way easier.

In the example below, I am using `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` to manipulate the border. `stroke-dasharray` stands for the length of dashes, and `stroke-dashoffset` means offset from where dashed line begins.

By default, I assigned `stroke-dasharray: 377;` and `stroke-dashoffset: 377;`. It means it uses 377px length of dashes and spaces in between, with 377px offset.

If you change `stroke-dashoffset` to `0`, it will gradually draw(reduce offset) the circle border. As the length of circumference is about 377px (2 x Pi x 60px), it will make a circle without any dashes.

At the last frame of the animation, as soon as you change the `stroke-dasharray` to smaller numbers, it will transform its border to dashes.

```css
circle {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: red;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 377;
  stroke-dashoffset: 377;
  animation: render 1s linear both;
}

@keyframes render {
  99% {
    stroke-dasharray: 377;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 5; 
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="60" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have no problem with even SGV as well, but in your example it starts with solid lines and once complete then it becomes dashed, is it possible if it start with dotted lines and end with the dotted lines? no solid lines at all.

Comment: Check [another answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42642830/2373800) for your question. thanks.